# Is there a way to improve the performance of saveAsTextFile method on spark

Tags: performance, apache-spark

I've processed large data in spark and stored them in HDFS.

However, I feel that the saveAsTextFile method is somewhat slower.

So I wonder if there is a way to improve its performance.

My original code (which is running slower than expected)

```
val data = sc.textFile("data", 200); 
data.
  flatMap(_.split(" ")).
  map(word => (word, 1)).
  reduceByKey(_ + _).
  saveAsTextFile("output")
```

When I add coalesce(1), the speed improves dramatically

```
val data = sc.textFile("data", 200); 
data.
   flatMap(_.split(" ")).
   map(word => (word, 1)).
   reduceByKey(_ + _).
   coalesce(1).
   saveAsTextFile("output")
```

Comment: I would recommend checking the spark master page for your job, it has a lot of details about timings of different parts of the job. You probably also want to check the # of files and sizes that you are writing to hdfs. You may be writing tons of small files, for instance.

Comment: Thanks for you reply!
Could you answer one more question? If you don't mind.
When I load text file using `sc.textFile()`, I set the partitioning parameter of this method to 200. Is this what you mean by "You may be writing tons of small files" ?

Comment: pls add the code which you have tried.

Comment: I will show you my results of two experiments with wordcount as an example.

1. `val data = sc.textFile("data", 200); data.flatMap(_.split(" ")).map(word => (word, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _).saveAsTextFile("output")`

2. `val data = sc.textFile("data", 200); data.flatMap(_.split(" ")).map(word => (word, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _).coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile("output")`

In the second case, spark app execution time was shorter.

I know that coalesce is reducing the number of partitions, but I do not know why these results came out.
Can you explain in detail?

Comment: Hi! @S.Kang, in the future, please add your code to your question for readability. I went ahead and added it for you. Additionally, when I said "you may be writing tons of small files", I meant the output of this job may be writing many, small files to HDFS. Check the output directory that you pass to saveAsTextFile.

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing your job is running slowly b/c you are asking for 200 partitions of your input. When you write your output to HDFS, it is writing 200 (probably small) files to HDFS. You notice the speed up when you coalesce down to 1.

I would suggest removing the 200 partitions in textFile and let Spark select the default parallelism.

```
val data = sc.textFile(inputDir) // no partitions specified
```

You may want to keep an eye on the file sizes written out at the end of the job still though. HDFS performs best when file sizes are close to a block size (I don't remember the default but around 256M I think).

Another reason more partitions can be slower is because Spark does setup/teardown per partition. There is a sweet spot to setting those numbers. Take a look at your Spark master, if there's 100ms of setup/teardown for 5ms of real work, you want less partitions for instance.

I always start with Spark setting to default though, and tweak from there as needed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!